# Href in complete citation in references/bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, hyperlink

**This is my current approach**

main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %removes border around links
\begin{document}
pixels\cite{ARTICLE:1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{References}
\bibliography{document.bib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib

```
@ARTICLE{ARTICLE:1,
AUTHOR = "Junhong, Zhang and Wei Lu and Xiaolin, Yin and Wanteng, Liu and Yuileong, Yeung",
TITLE = "Binary image steganography based on joint distortion measurement",
JOURNAL = "Elsevier",
YEAR = "23 December 2018",
NOTE = "\href{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329882001_Binary_Image_Steganography_Based_on_Joint_Distortion_Measurement}{Available here}",
```

}

**Which gives me output like this**

Citation.jpg

[image: citation]

Reference.jpg

[image: citation reference with link as a note]

**So what I want instead of Available here link I want the complete reference string which consists of author, year, title, etc to be a link. Something like NewReference.jpg**

NewReference.jpg

[image: Citation reference with link]

**Update**

Commands I'm using to compile are

```
pdflatex main.tex
bibtex bibliography.bib
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below mentioned source. Use `\url` instead of `\href` in the bibliography graph. Change the bibliographystyle as `ieeetran` instead of `\ieeetr`. Apply changes to your original source files and compile it. Enjoy.

The updated source of `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %removes border around links


\begin{document}
pixels~\cite{ARTICLE:1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{References}
\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetran}
\end{document}
```

Update the bibligraphy (.bib) file as:

```
@ARTICLE{ARTICLE:1,
AUTHOR = "Junhong, Zhang and Wei Lu and Xiaolin, Yin and Wanteng, Liu and Yuileong, Yeung",
TITLE = "Binary image steganography based on joint distortion measurement",
JOURNAL = "Elsevier",
YEAR = "23 December 2018",
NOTE = "\url{https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329882001_Binary_Image_Steganography_Based_on_Joint_Distortion_Measurement}{Available here}"
```

Edit 2:

If you want the reference to be formatted according to Springer Style. Change the `bibliographystyle` from `ieeetran` to `spbasic`. For this you have to download the file named `spbasic.bst` and save it into the working directory. The source of `spbasic.bst` is: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~lecuyer/mcqmc08/proceedings/spbasic.bst. Further you need to add (`\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`) into the preamble, which is shown below in `Edit 2`. Further, you need to specify clearly the volume number, issue and page number in the `.bib` file, which are missing at present. Hope this helps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %removes border around links

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
pixels~\cite{ARTICLE:1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{References}
\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\end{document}
```

Edit 3: The attached image is about references in `Elsevier` Format article.

For this, the source of `main.tex` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %removes border around links

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
pixels~\cite{ZHANG2019,2013cao}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{References}
\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\end{document}
```

The used `.bib file` is as follows:

```
@article{ZHANG2019,
title = "Binary image steganography based on joint distortion measurement",
journal = "Journal of Visual Communication and Image Representation",
volume = "58",
pages = "600 - 605",
year = "2019",
author = "Junhong Zhang and Wei Lu and Xiaolin Yin and Wanteng Liu and Yuileong Yeung",
}


@ARTICLE{2013cao,
author={H. {Cao} and A. C. {Kot}},
journal={IEEE Transactions on Information Forensics and Security},
title={On Establishing Edge Adaptive Grid for Bilevel Image Data Hiding},
year={2013},
volume={8},
number={9},
pages={1508-1518},
month={September},
}
```

Hope this helps. The screenshot is attached for your reference.

[image]

Comment: after your answer only thing got added was the change of href to url, which makes url visible and no one want urls to be visible in the reference.

Comment: what you suggested is changing the style format but i think problem isn't concerned with the style. Whatever style I would use, I want the whole citation to be clickable and blue in color so that anyone can reference to the article.

Comment: where can I find the file _elsarticle-num.bst_ file to provide the style of bibliography

Comment: The link for elsarticle-num.bst ``http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/elsarticle/elsarticle-num.bst``